# Как сделать чтобы бот проверял все сообщения

Tags: python, telebot

Написал бота на PyTelegramBotApi
пример кода:

```
@bot.message_handler()
def get_user_text(message):
    text = message.text.lower()
    if text == 'ботяра':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'нуя')

    elif text == 'скинь фотку':
        photo = open('h9.png', 'rb')
        bot.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo)
```

Добавил в группу,работает только когда отвечаешь ему на сообщения,
как сделать чтобы он проверял все сообщения из группы? Которые даже не адресованы ему.